# How is self.prompt being skipped in this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was looking at someone's code asked a year about having trouble with making a game and I came across a question about another part of their code that I cannot figure out. The following is the code...

**game_runner.py**

```
from game_map import *

class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next_room = self.start

        while True:
            print '\n'
            print '-' * 7
            print next_room.__doc__
            next_room.proceed()

firstroom = Chillin()

my_game = Runner(firstroom)

my_game.play()
```

**game_map.py**

```
from sys import exit


class Chillin(object):
    """It's 8pm on a Friday night in Madison. You're lounging on the couch with your 
roommates watching Dazed and Confused. What is your first drink?
    1. beer
    2. whiskey
    3. vodka
    4. bowl
"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.prompt = '> '

    def proceed(self):
        drink = raw_input(self.prompt)

        if drink == '1' or drink == 'beer':
            print '\n Anytime is the right time.'
            print 'You crack open the first beer and sip it down.'
            room = Pregame()
            return room
        #rest of drinks will be written the same way


class Pregame(object):
    """It's time to really step up your pregame.
How many drinks do you take?
"""

    def proceed(self):
        drinks = raw_input('> ')
    #and so on
```

So my question here is when `firstroom = Chillin()` the `def __init__` is called, but somehow the `self.prompt = '> '` doesn't show up until after the While loop loops through once. I am still quite new to coding so this question may seem vague but hopefully someone can answer because I am very confused. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect a variable assignment to give output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.prompt doesnt get displayed until proceed() is called.

proceed() is called at the end of the while loop

Comment: Oh awesome yea I see that now, I didn't realize it was just setting a variable but not actually doing anything with it until proceed() is called. Thank you!